# Using String.format() string in a toast Android

Tags: android, string-formatting, toast

I am trying to figure out how to input a formatted string to use in a toast. The toast works with a plain old string, such as

```
string s1 = "You scored"
```

But it will not work with String.format(). Why is this? Is there any way to work around this? I already know it will work if I do

```
Toast.makeText(this, "You scored: " + score + "%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I want the percentage to not have any decimal numbers. I have searched around but could not find an answer.

This is what doesn't work:

```
float score = ((float) mNumberCorrect / 6)*100;

Toast.makeText(this, String.format("You scored: %d", score) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: check below answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to write `%f` in place of `%d` like below.

```
float score = ((float) mNumberCorrect / 6)*100;

Toast.makeText(this, String.format("You scored: %f", score) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Hahah wow that is a dumb mistake. I thought it was something to do with the toast method.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this :

```
float score = ((float) mNumberCorrect / 6)*100;

Toast.makeText(this, String.format("You scored: %d %%", score) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The %% escapes the percentage (%) letter and gives you the desired output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid decimal points, try using an `int` instead.

```
int score = Math.round(mNumberCorrect / 6 * 100)
Toast.makeText(this, String.format("You scored: %d", score) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Note that you were using `%d` which denotes an integer, rather than a float. See [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for details on what to use for different data types.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you may get float value in string format and then show in Toast as above

```
 float score = ((float) mNumberCorrect/ 6)*100;
    String sr = String.valueOf(score);

    Toast.makeText(this,"You scored: " + sr , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```